# Boom length of a Yagi antenna

Tags: yagi

Apologies in advance if this question is too straightforward. I was browsing for some information about the dimensions of Yagis. This [yagi listed by PEOSAT](https://www.pe0sat.vgnet.nl/antenna/cue-dee/), called Cue Dee 15144AN, is stated to have a boom length of 6.45 meters. To my understanding, boom length is the length from tip to tip. Looking at this antenna, the tip-to-tip length doesn't seem to be 6.45 meters. Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the boom length?

Comment: why not - the elements are 1 metre long, the boom could be 6.5 m?

Answer (score 2):

The boom is the center supporting section which holds all of the individual reflector, driven element, and director elements. The mounting bracket for larger yagi antennas is normally at the center of the boom.

The tip to tip measurement you are talking about is the length of the elements, which are all usually slightly different.

[image]